# how to send a set of objects in a template?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I send a set of objects in a pattern.

model:

```
class Modal(models.Model):      
    message = models.CharField(
        max_length=2000, 
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
```

view:

```
def custom_proc(request):   
    modal = Modal.get_entries()
    return{
        'request': request,
        'modal': Modal.objects.all(),
    }
```

template:

```
<br />
{% for entry in modals %}
    {{ entry.id }}
{% endfor %}
<br />
```

the result is displayed:

```
[<Modal: Modal object>, <Modal: Modal object>, <Modal: Modal object>]
```

but it should be displayed:

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: There is no way that the template you have posted would display that, unless you have some where `{{ modals }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing a Modal object, and that's how it's represented as a string by default. You can print a specific field, e.g. `{{ entry.message }}`, or define a `__unicode__` method on `Modal` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode).

Comment: I made a typo. Now I have corrected the issue. does not work entry.message or entry.id

Comment: You may have made another typo: in view, you've got modal without an s, and in the template you're looping through modals. Are those definitely the same in your code?